# How to call SSRS report in ASP.NET Core MVC application?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, asp.net-core-mvc, ssrs-2012

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC application using C# and Dapper. In my project I have to use the report so can anyone suggest to me which path is best

**Either** create a separate SSRS solution and call it **OR** create a REPORT folder in the same ASP.NET Core application.

I am searching on GOOGLE and most of the forums suggest calling the SSRS project into the ASP.NET Core application.

Can you please provide me with how to CALL SSRS reports in my ASP.NET Core app?

Please provide me a link through which I can follow the steps and finish my project task.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63561572/ssrs-reports-with-net-core-3-1-mvc-application).