# Asp.net Core SSRS Viewer

Tags: .net-core, reporting-services

Does anybody know of a way to view SSRS server reports in an asp.net core application (3.0) without purchasing 3rd party solutions? I have found some old solutions/nuget packages but they are outdated, hacky and don't really work well anymore.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the best I've found so far is ngx-ssrs-reportviewer, which you can get from GitHub.  I've implemented it in Angular using an IFrame, but it has the downside of requiring the authenticated user have a server account or a second login challenge will happen.  For an internal corporate applications this is fine (which I understand to be the use case for SSRS), but for an internet application this is a big problem. A potential solution to this was posted by iceman here:
[Angular ngx-ssrs-reportviewer Credential Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60189729/angular-ngx-ssrs-reportviewer-credential-problems/64581660#64581660)